# assigning id with setAttribute

Tags: javascript, class, setattribute

```
function createNewTodo(todoItem) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute("id", todoItem.id);

    var spanTodo = document.createElement("span");
    spanTodo.innerHTML =
        todoItem.who + " needs to " + todoItem.task + " by " + todoItem.dueDate;

    var spanDone = document.createElement("span");
    spanDone.setAttribute("id", todoItem.id); //where I try to assign id
    if (!todoItem.done) {
        spanDone.setAttribute("class", "notDone");
        spanDone.innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
    else {
        spanDone.setAttribute("class", "done");
        spanDone.innerHTML = "&nbsp;&#10004;&nbsp;";        
    }
    spanDone.setAttribute("id", todoItem.id);

    var spanDelete = document.createElement("span");
    spanDelete.setAttribute("id", todoItem.id);
    spanDelete.setAttribute("class", "delete");
    spanDelete.innerHTML = "&nbsp;&#10007;&nbsp;";

    spanDelete.onclick = deleteItem;
    spanDone.onclick = updateDone;

    li.appendChild(spanDone);
    li.appendChild(spanTodo);
    li.appendChild(spanDelete);

    return li;
}

function updateDone(e) {
  var spanClicked = e.target.id;
  console.log("you clicked this span" + id);
 }
```

My goal here is to update spanDone when a user clicks on it. I need to assign each span an individual id that I would get from an object I made earlier in my code called todoItem. When I look in my console though I keep getting the error "id is not defined". I don't understand why I cannot assign the id there. Any suggestions on how to modify my code so that I can assign spanDone with the todoItem id?

Comment: Which line does the error refer to?

Comment: the very last line console.log("you clicked this span" + id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to use your variable instead?

```
function updateDone(e) {
  var spanClicked = e.target.id;
  console.log("you clicked this span" + spanClicked);
}
```

Comment: Hey, it's all good. Accept the answer (click the checkmark) and we're even. :-)

Comment: Yo, new guy... get back here and pay the piper! I work for points, you know. Nothing's free in this world. ;-)